# Angular 2 using ng require versus import

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Am from the Angular 1 world going into Angular 2 and trying to better understand options with Angular 2's routing. Found a decent tutorial and they are using at import like:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

within the routes.js (though the tutorial is using typescript (.ts) of which I am not).

That said, if I strictly just try using the import rather than what I had initially of (note: mine does not show the @angular/router yet within the routes.js file):

```
var ng = require('@angular/core');
```

So I like the premise of what they are doing, and trying to figure how I can implement this.

My root index.js looks like:

```
require('core-js/client/shim');
require('zone.js/dist/zone');

require('@angular/common');
require('rxjs');

require('bootstrap')
require('./index.scss');

var ngCore = require('@angular/core');
var ngPbd = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic');
var AppModule = require('./app');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    ngCore.enableProdMode();
} else {
    Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity; // eslint-disable-line dot-notation
    require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
}

ngPbd.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Then my index.js for app is:

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
var ng = require('@angular/core');
var ngPlatformBrowser = require('@angular/platform-browser');
var uiRouter = require('ui-router-ng2');
var fa = require('font-awesome-loader');

var myRoutes = require('./routes');
var mainComponent = require('./main');

module.exports = uiRouter.UIRouterModule({
    imports: [
        ngPlatformBrowser.BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        mainComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        uiRouter.provideUIRouter({ configClass: myRoutes.MyUIRouterConfig })
    ],
    states: myRoutes.STATES,
    bootstrap: [uiRouter.UIView]
})(
    ng.Class({
        constructor: function() {}
    })
);
```

Any suggestions and help to get me to a better point with this? Is this simply a typescript thing?

Thanks much.

Comment: Why aren't you using TS?

Comment: For one, I do not yet know Typescript and two, we started this with plain vanilla JavaScript. It would be ideal to go to TS at some point, but for now, this is where we are at.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this by not using what the framework was built for. Best of luck.

Comment: you don't so much need to _know_ typescript since it's a superset of javascript. You could technically write only javascript in your ts files and it would work fine, though typescript offers some great benefits

Comment: Well, broke down yesterday and converted to TypeScript. Now it is going much easier....